# Will not open Project

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, windows-mobile, path

My solution in in c# has two projects. Each in their own seperate folder. I can change the first folder name containing the first project and it does not affect the program. I can open and run it with no complains. However, when I change the second project folder name it gives the following warning:

One or more projects in the solution could not be loaded for the following reason(s):

The project file or web has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer.

These projects will be labled as unavailable in Solution Explorer. Expand the node to show the reason the project could not be loaded.

When I expand the node it says:

The project file or web cannot be found.

I have just renamed the folder. Where can I access the path to change this?

I have tried making a new project with the correct name. This seems to work but I now encounter another problem. Since this is a Windows Mobile application, when I debug I get the deploy box asking which mobile device I would like to run my solution on. I pick the Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator. The emulator comes up but after about 4 seconds I get another deploy box coming up asking me the same thing. I pick the same device and my program runs on the second emulator with no problems. I have no clue why Inow get a second deploy box. When all I done was make a new project and copy the classes from the old one to the new one.

Can someone please tell me what happend and what I can do in both cases.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Either remove the project from the solution and re-add it, or open up the solution file in a text editor and change the path there.

Comment: +1 most of the time its just easier to re-add it... takes like 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes I re-added it and all seems fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the path information in the solution file and verify that path information against the real path on the file system?